# How to edit .eps file in Gimp or Photopea?

Tags: gimp, eps, photopea

[image]

I have an .EPS containing text which I downloaded. However, I don't know how to edit the EPS file ?

I can load it up into Photopea, however, i can't seem to edit it like a .psd file, im confused.

I've attached the .EPS font to this message but its so confusing, all i need the font to say is "Flavours" but it has the sample text is "HONEY" and the whole alphabet of letters underneath.

Please check it out, can anyone help me on how i can edit this please. Thanks

Here is a download to the .EPS Text I am trying to edit, if it helps clarify anyhing. https://easyupload.io/0o0rji

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that (if your file is indeed vector) you'll have to re-arrange the letters yourself; it's not a font where you can just re-type the text. You need a vector editing program for that

Comment: So if I want flavours for example - I will need to re-arrange the letters below it, to spell flavours myself ? Here is a download of the .eps file, if that helps clarify anything . Another thing I am stuck on, if i have to re-arrange the letters, which i just tried to do, what do i do ? delete all the layers that are not needed and keep FLAVOURS ? If so, how to I increase size the font ? and how to i move the multiple layers for 1 letter all at same time ? For example, i move the F and there is a black F layer underneath it. Is there a way to move all the F layers in one go ?

Comment: Here is the download to the .EPS Text file I am trying to edit, if it helps clarify anything. https://easyupload.io/0o0rji

Comment: I just checked the file. It's vector. So, you really would be better to use a vector image editor.  Inkscape (which is free and open source) or Adobe Illustrator (not free) can open it and edit it.  The letters are just outlines so you'll need to copy and paste them to make up words.

Comment: Note that depending on where and how you acquired the eps file, resharing/relinking to it *may* be a violation of terms you agreed to.

Comment: I'm starting to get so frustrated with this, you wouldn't even believe! I have been trying 2 days straight and can't get this working! Feel like chucking my laptop of the wall. It's probably a 5 minute job for most, however, its going on and on and on. This is stopping me from finishing the design! I just tried inkscape there, followed a youtube video on how to open the .eps folder with windows 10 and ghostscript, do all that stuff... boom, doesn't even load. All I want is that text to say flavours, why the hell isn't it just working, getting so frustrated with this stuff.

Comment: I can sympathize with the frustration. However, none of that is even remotely helpful in solving your problem.

Comment: @CandyShop - it does open in Inkscape 1.0 in Windows 10 with ghostscript installed. [I just tried it](https://imgur.com/ewxS99W) and it is certainly working.

Answer (score 0):

You **do not** necessarily *want* to use Gimp or Photopea for this. Those are *raster* applications and will not take advantages of the vector nature of the objects in the EPS file.

If you *must* use a raster image editor, you will need to *select* and copy each letter as you need it, then move it into position. This can be done, but is much more effort. The entire eps will be seen as one single image in a raster editor and you will need to separate *each* letter from the entire image first.

---

With a *vector application* - Inkscape, Adobe Illustrator, Sketch, CorelDraw, Xara, etc. merely open the eps file and then move the individual groupings which create each letter.

You should then be able to select and move each individual letter into a position to suit your needs easily with a *vector* editor.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, dammm bro, thats what i need to do but i tried with inkscape and using the ghostscript to load from windows 10 and it didnt work, do you mind me asking, how u edited the above image ?

Comment: I merely opened it in Adobe Illustrator and moved the letters.

Answer (score 0):

Photopea quite surprisingly opens your EPS as a high stack of layers. Every layer contains a bitmap shape which is masked by a path. It's quite same as Photoshop's vector shapes.

A lucky case here is that shapes which belong to the same letter are adjacent layers. I selected those which belong to the P:

[image]

The shapes can be moved freely, even a multiple selection. But scaling is a nightmare. You can scale one path at a time and you very likely will lose their relative placements. Putting them to a folder helps nothing. The same thing for making a smart object, that functionality is very limited in Photopea.

You can delete those layers you do not need. Move the needed ones  to the approximately right formation to keep the image size reasonable in pixels. Crop the extra area off. Resize the image. I guess you want at least 500% size (see NOTE1). That's possible with no quality loss because the shapes have vector masks. Place the shapes manually when the scaling is done.

You can define every letter as a separate smart object. Select the shapes in the layers panel and right click. The functionality of smart objects isn't like in Photoshop, but at least you can move a letter as one. Do not attempt to scale a smart object in Photopea. It doesn't work acceptably.

My opinion: Do as user Scott has written. Get a program which opens EPS as vector. Photopea isn't still good enough for editing vector shapes.

NOTE1 Photopea's vectors are actually bitmap images which have vector masks. Lossless scaling is possible only in an application which understands their structure. It's best to make them as big as finally needed because you very likely must rasterize them for the final application.

Comment: Ok. I've download and finally got adobe illistrator. Can you confirm, is there a way to move the letter all in one go. For example, i tried to move the F but it moves the gold part first and then i have to move the black color to go under the gold. I cant help but think that there has to be an easier to move all layers in one go for that letter ? do you know how ? Also do u know how i can create a transparent background ? sorry for this im not super techy

Comment: The brown background is a shape that can be deleted, moved aside or hidden in the layers panel. You can select all four parts of a letter and group them (=Object > Group). Groups can be selected, moved, scaled and rotated as a whole. Illustrator isn't the only well working tool. Affinity Designer handled this case as well (tested by me) But if you can afford Illustrator, keep it. Illustrator has 15 years more development behind it and many properties that Affinity or Inkscape users only can dream of.